# Retrieve list of class from DB using Entity Framework filtered by a computed property?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a DB class with the following properties:

```
public string AwsS3Key { get; set; }
public bool PendingS3Upload => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AwsS3Key);
```

I'm trying to pull a list of data from my context by filtering based on the `PendingS3Upload` property. However, I get the following error:

> The specified type member 'PendingS3Upload' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

How can I pull data from my table with respect to the "computed" property `PendingS3Upload` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark your property with the `[NotMapped]` attribute. Although you won't be able to Query this at the Database level, only in Memory using `ToList()` or `AsEnumnerable()` in some use cases this is out of the question due to large datasets etc.

If you need to query this on the database then assuming you're using SQL Server you can use computed columns.

[Computed Column Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29)

If you want this to be Code First then you'll have to execute some SQL when you initialise the database or migrating.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName 
ADD PendingS3Upload AS (CAST(CASE WHEN AwsS3Key <> '' = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT))
```

Then change your Class Property to

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)] 
public bool PendingS3Upload { get; private set;}
```

(I can't remember if the private set will work)

Comment: Ahh. How would I go about created computed columns, specifically from my Code First approach?

Comment: @DanielBrown I've Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ isn't able to translate computed properties to an SQL statement which is why you're getting that error.  You have two options for this.  You can pull the data locally using ToList() and then apply the filter like this:

```
var result = Context.YourClass.ToList().Where(c => c.PendingS3Upload).ToList();
```

or you can translate the logic to something LINQ can handle like this:

```
var result = Context.YourClass.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.AwsS3Key)).ToList();
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to force the property to map to the DB, and then continue to filter on the property? Neither of the options you've mentioned are all that desirable.